# What are these things on the side of the GSLV Mk 3 SRBs?

Tags: identify-this-object, gslv

Circled in green

Images found by looking up “gslv mk 3”

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hydraulic fluid tanks for the solid boosters' blow-down thrust vector control system.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LVM3

[image]

FNC = Flex Nozzle Control

https://web.archive.org/web/20211011095054/https://www.isro.gov.in/sites/default/files/flipping_book/LVM-3/CARE/files/assets/common/downloads/LVM3-brochure.pdf

[image]

https://spaceflight101.com/members/wp-content/uploads/sites/54/2017/02/GSLV-MkIII.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the other answer:

In the future, these structures will be used to house the batteries (and perhaps other electronics) for the **electro-mechanical** actuation system (which will replace the electro-hydraulic system mentioned in the other answer)

The electro-mechanical system is expected to replace the electro-hydraulic system in the [human-rated version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LVM3#Human-rating) of the LVM3.